# Unix Script to split one big file into multiple files with two pairs of a tag each in a file with a naming convention on filename

Tags: bash, shell, unix

**I am writing a Shell script to split one big file into multiple files with two pairs of a tag each in a file and those small filenames must follow a naming convention.**

Example:-

Big File Name : abcdef123.xml
Contents:

```
<parent>
    <child>
        <code1><code1>
        <text1><text1>
    </child>
    <child1>
        <code2><code2>
        <text2><text2>
    </child1>
    <child>
        <code3><code3>
        <text3><text3>
    </child>
    <child1>
        <code4><code4>
        <text4><text4>
    </child1>
    <child>
        <code5><code5>
        <text5><text5>
    </child>
    <child1>
        <code6><code6>
        <text6><text6>
    </child1>
    <child>
        <code7><code7>
        <text7><text7>
    </child>
    <child1>
        <code8><code8>
        <text8><text8>
    </child1>
</parent>
```

The Unix shell script should split this big file into multiple files (with 2 pairs of `<child>` & `<child1>` each in the file) having the following criteria and take user input for file name convention (the date with miliseconds can remain same in all file name but variable 'j' should change):-

**Criteria:-**

1. Add header `'<parent>'` and tail `'</parent>'` to each file.
2. File name should be in format of `'UserinputstringMMDDYYYYHHMMSSMIL_n increment.xml'` (where MIL is milliseconds and 'n increment' will be like 001, 002, 003....)
3. No two file should have same filename

Example Big File splits:-

file 1= stack_10132020134434789_001.xml

Contents :-

```
<parent>
    <child>
        <code1><code1>
        <text1><text1>
    </child>
    <child1>
        <code2><code2>
        <text2><text2>
    </child1>
    <child>
        <code3><code3>
        <text3><text3>
    </child>
    <child1>
        <code4><code4>
        <text4><text4>
    </child1>
</parent>
```

file 2= stack_10132020134434791_002.xml

Contents :-

```
<parent>
    <child>
        <code5><code5>
        <text5><text5>
    </child>
    <child1>
        <code6><code6>
        <text6><text6>
    </child1>
    <child>
        <code7><code7>
        <text7><text7>
    </child>
    <child1>
        <code8><code8>
        <text8><text8>
    </child1>
</parent>
```

Script I was trying :-

````
csplit -ksf part. src.xml

n=000

E.g. Enter beginning of file name :
User entered-> stack
read userinput

j=n+1

$date= date +%m%d%Y%H%M%S%3N

filename=$userinput$date_$j.xml```
````

Comment: You need to use a dedicated XML tool like `xmlstarlet` or write a script in a language with a proper XML parser, like maybe Python. There is no way to pull this off with plain regex.

Answer (score 0):

sample.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<parent>
    <child>
        <code1>aa</code1>
        <text1>aat</text1>
    </child>
    <child1>
        <code2>aa2</code2>
        <text2>aat2</text2>
    </child1>
    <child>
        <code3>bb</code3>
        <text3>bbt</text3>
    </child>
    <child1>
        <code4>bb2</code4>
        <text4>bbt2</text4>
    </child1>
    <child>
        <code5>cc</code5>
        <text5>cct</text5>
    </child>
    <child1>
        <code6>cc2</code6>
        <text6>cct2</text6>
    </child1>
    <child>
        <code7>dd</code7>
        <text7>ddt</text7>
    </child>
    <child1>
        <code8>dd2</code8>
        <text8>ddt2</text8>
    </child1>
</parent>
```

parser.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

PARENT='parent'
CHILD1='child'
CHILD2='child1'
INPUT_FILE='sample.xml'

NUM_OF_CHILDS=$(cat $INPUT_FILE | grep "<$CHILD1>" | wc -l)

FILE_NUM=1
for i in $(seq 1 2 $NUM_OF_CHILDS); do
  echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
  echo "FILENAME_"$(date +%s%N)"_$FILE_NUM.xml"
  echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
  echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>'
  echo '<'$PARENT'>'
  xmllint --xpath "(//parent/$CHILD1[$i])" $INPUT_FILE
  xmllint --xpath "(//parent/$CHILD2[$i])" $INPUT_FILE
  xmllint --xpath "(//parent/$CHILD1[$(( i + 1 ))])" $INPUT_FILE
  xmllint --xpath "(//parent/$CHILD2[$(( i + 1 ))])" $INPUT_FILE
  echo '</'$PARENT'>'
  FILE_NUM=$(( FILE_NUM + 1 ))
done
```

output:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
FILENAME_1603633647540475038_1.xml
-----------------------------------------------------
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<parent>
<child>
        <code1>aa</code1>
        <text1>aat</text1>
    </child>
<child1>
        <code2>aa2</code2>
        <text2>aat2</text2>
    </child1>
<child>
        <code3>bb</code3>
        <text3>bbt</text3>
    </child>
<child1>
        <code4>bb2</code4>
        <text4>bbt2</text4>
    </child1>
</parent>
```

```
-----------------------------------------------------
FILENAME_1603633647547254647_2.xml
-----------------------------------------------------
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<parent>
<child>
        <code5>cc</code5>
        <text5>cct</text5>
    </child>
<child1>
        <code6>cc2</code6>
        <text6>cct2</text6>
    </child1>
<child>
        <code7>dd</code7>
        <text7>ddt</text7>
    </child>
<child1>
        <code8>dd2</code8>
        <text8>ddt2</text8>
    </child1>
</parent>
```

Looks like you plan to use output files as xml, so indents and newlines not matter. In other case try to play with `xmllint` parameters.
Other details such as file naming convention are easy to change, so it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for this. It is working for me.

However, I wanted to know how I can create files from this. I mean 'FILENAME_1603633647540475038_1.xml' & 'FILENAME_1603633647547254647_2.xml' needs to be two created as two separate files in the directory but I am getting as output only in Linux in linux workspace

Comment: You can use `echo "some-output" >> /your_directory/FILENAME_$(date +%s%N)_$FILE_NUM.xml` to redirect your output in file instead of standard output